# How to calculate the daywise average and multiply it to number of rows in that particular day

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have daywise excel data of four months which contains hourly data from 10 AM to 3 PM or sometimes 10 AM to 2 PM....1PM ..... like wise it is varying. The column A contains the date, Column B contains the time and column C and D has the data which i want to average for each day and multiply it to the number of occurrence.
For example If I have a data in column C and D for 17 Oct from 10 AM to 3PM (6 Hours)..Then i want to average these hourly data for a day and multiply it by 6. Since my interval of hourly data is not fixed, that is why i want a code which can average the daywise data and multiply it to the number of occurrence. I want to average the data 1 and data 2 for each day and to multiply its average by the number of occurrence of data in that particular day
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not exactly get what does "average these hourly data" means since **Average** basically means summing all data within a day and dividing them to the occurrences. If you again multiply by the number of daily occurrence, you will get the summed value again.

Apart from above unclear point, un-merging all column B cells and filling all your rows with date data will be very helpful in order to form a quick sum or average formula based on the date conditions.

After doing above step, you may enter the below formula to E2 to get the sum of Col:C, for all data dated A2; 17-Oct.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2)
```

And you may get the occurences on the date of your row data, you should use the formula and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)
```

In combination of above 2 formulas, you may calculate the averages and/or date occurrences. I may write an exact solution if you may enter your requested values into COL:E and provide a screenshot.

Comment: ...Thank you very very much..It is really helpfull...Actually i got confused..because i had a bulk of data ...I just want summation of each day... I have used the your formullas ...and got the results ...But i have issue ..please solve it if u can ..i am getting the repeated results for each day ..i just want to keep the single results and discard the other ... Here i am attaching the screen shoot

Comment: There might be a bunch of ways to do this but most easily, I would choose to use an IF in order to see whether the date value of our row is same with the previous row's date (means if our row is or is not the first occurrence of that day). So our F3 can be something like: `=IF(A3=A2;"";SUMIFS(C:C;A:A;A3)*COUNTIFS(A:A;A3))`